# How to dynamically insert the list data into an html table

Tags: jquery, html

I am using bootstrap. This is the table in which i want the all the list items to appear.

```
<table id="playlist_table" class="table table-bordered">
    <caption class="text-center">PLAYLIST</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Song Name</th>
            <th>Singer</th>
            <th>Film</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="palylist_table_data">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my playlist:

```
<ul id="playlist" class="hidden">
    <li Src="Ek%20duje%20ke%20vaaste%20serial%20title%20song.mp3" Title="Ek Duje Ke Vasste" Singer="Unkown" Cover="Album images/ek.jpg"> Ek Duje Ke VAste
    </li>
    <li Src="Lak.mp3" Title="Lakshya ko HAr haal mein Paana HAi" Singer="Shankar Mahadevan" Cover="Album images/lakshya.jpg"> LAkshya
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is the Jquery code I have written but i am not able to get any data in table.

```
$('.playlist li').each(function(){
        var song = $(this).attr('Src');
        var title = $(this).attr('Title');
        var singer = $(this).attr('Singer');
        var cover = $(this).attr('Cover');

        $('#playlist_table_data').html('<tr>' + '<td>' + '*' + '</td>' + '<td>' + song + '</td>' + '<td>' + singer + '</td>' + '<td>' + title + '</td>' + '</tr>');        
    });
```

Comment: Use `$('#playlist li')` instead `$('.playlist li')`. You don't have `.playlist class`

Comment: There's more issues than that...

Comment: @cale_b yes, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of selector issues, as well as using the incorrect jQuery function [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Here's a [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/fqpdy88a/)

Note the revised jQuery below:

```
// Use a document ready, to be sure it waits until all html is loaded
jQuery(function($) {
  // Your ul is ID playlist (#playlist), not CLASS playlist (.playlist)
  $('#playlist li').each(function() {
    var song = $(this).attr('Src');
    var title = $(this).attr('Title');
    var singer = $(this).attr('Singer');
    var cover = $(this).attr('Cover');

    // Your table is #playlist_table, not #playlist_table_data
    // using .html() will replace table contents.  You want .append(), to add them to the end of the table
    $('#playlist_table').append('<tr>' + '<td>' + '*' + '</td>' + '<td>' + song + '</td>' + '<td>' + singer + '</td>' + '<td>' + title + '</td>' + '</tr>');

  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Since playlist is an ID element, use '#' instead of '.'

```
$('#playlist li').each(function() {...//code here});
```

And change the last line like the following: (append() instead of html())

```
$('#playlist_table_data').append('<tr>' + '<td>' + '*' + '</td>' + '<td>' + song + '</td>' + '<td>' + singer + '</td>' + '<td>' + title + '</td>' + '</tr>');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.